# rails view display the unwanted activerecord instance info

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My code in the view file is:

```
<%= @tweets.each do |tweet|%>
    <%= tweet.content %><br>
<% end %>
```

It always display, besides the tweet.content field, like follows:

```
My tweet text...
#<Tweet:0x10368d018>
```

What is wrong?? How to get ride of the second line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are rendering the expression in the first line. Try this:

```
<% @tweets.each do |tweet|%>
   <%= tweet.content %><br>
<% end %>
```